# UTC Time is not getting stored in oracle column(TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE) using JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, timestamp-with-timezone

I am getting UTC time in string format that we need to persist into database.

from UTC datetime string Calender object created using below code.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

        OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(rqTime,formatter);

        System.out.println(dateTime);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.setTime(Date.from(dateTime.toInstant()));
```

Then set above created calender instance to JPA

```
        EventDetails eventDetails = new EventDetails();
        eventDetails.setTimeWithZone(cal);
        event.insertEventDetails(eventDetails);
```

Entity class information

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mytimestamptz")
public class EventDetails implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name ="made_on" , columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
@Type(type="com.elitecore.isl.bl.xlink.custom.UTCCalendarType")
private Calendar timeWithZone ; 

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_EVENTID", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name ="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
private Long id;
```

This code insert UTC DAte String "2016-01-01T13:14:15+0000" as "01-JAN-2016 13:14:15 +0530" in database even if we have specified the timezone information (Refer UTCCalendarType).

UTCCalendarType created to store datetime in UTC format in database

```
public class UTCCalendarType extends CalendarType {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final TimeZone UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

/**
 * This is the original code from the class, with two changes. First we pull
 * it out of the result set with an example Calendar. Second, we set the new
 * calendar up in UTC.
 */
@Override
public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
    Timestamp ts = rs.getTimestamp(name, new GregorianCalendar(UTC));
    if (ts != null) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(UTC);
        cal.setTime(ts);
        return cal;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws SQLException {
    final Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
    cal.setTimeZone(UTC);

    System.out.println("IST TIME : "+cal.getTime());

    st.setTimestamp(index, new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime()),Calendar.getInstance(UTC));

}
```

}

I am not getting whats going wrong in this code.
why it is storing ASIA/KOLKATA TIMEZONE in database.
Kindly provide valuable input on this.

Comment: I don't know java/jpa so this may be a dumb question, but where's the code that inserts the value into the database? How are you passing the timestamp value across? My guess is that your db's server is set at the ASIA/KOLKATA timezone, and that when you pass the timestamp value across, you're not specifying the timezone (yes, I know that "Z" means UTC in the ISO timestamp format, but the Oracle db doesn't have any meaning attached to it in its timezone format mask) and the timestamp value is therefore being stored as if it were in the local timezone rather than UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a problem of data representation: the date is stored correctly, but the DBMS (or the query browser) shows it in its local format.

You can test if it's the case by using specific functions (e.g. `sys_extract_utc(timestamp)` for ORACLE), or by comparing with some other valid stored date by query.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have checked using sys_extract_utc it's not storing the UTC time.